# Turn off or modify recent apps list

Tags: android, list

Is there way to interact with the recent apps list which appears when you long press the home button? I would like to turn it off completely or if that is not possible to clear the entries.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not too sure if you could turn it off completely, but if you just want to exclude your app from appearing there, you could set `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in your manifest.xml.

Have a look at [getRunningTasks of ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to get a list of recently launched app.

> **public
>   List
>   getRunningTasks (int maxNum)**
>
> Return a list of the tasks that are
>   currently running, with the most
>   recent being first and older ones
>   after in order. Note that "running"
>   does not mean any of the task's code
>   is currently loaded or activity -- the
>   task may have been frozen by the
>   system, so that it can be restarted in
>   its previous state when next brought
>   to the foreground.

At last, this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934355/overriding-the-home-key-long-press-in-a-category-home-activity) provides some information regarding overriding the longpressed home button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen on the focus of your activity :

When your activity is loosing focus, fire an Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS intent.

More infos and sample code here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12652490/1555824)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is to do this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

            Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

        if(!hasFocus) {
            Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

            Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }
}// all credit goes here: http://www.juliencavandoli.com/how-to-disable-recent-apps-dialog-on-long-press-home-button/
```

This is not my own code, but this just hides the recent apps list from showing. Anything else, like this:
[Android, how to clear the recent task list which could get from Home button in most phone? Reflection is a possible way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890415/android-how-to-clear-the-recent-task-list-which-could-get-from-home-button-in-m/16258043#16258043)

requires a root or something else