# Change the long click functionality of the home button

Tags: android, launcher, taskmanager, long-press, long-click

I am looking for Android 'trick' to change the functionality of the long click on the home button.
Currently, long click on the home button open the task manager.
Instead, I want the long click to act as short click which means take us to the home page of the default launcher.

Ideally, this trick will work for all Android versions, but if it will work for 2.3.x only or 4.x.x only then this is good enough.

(I managed to disable the long click with Android 2.3.x but now i am looking to use the long click as short click)