# Clear all recent tasks Programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to remove all recent tasks through a program. Before posting a question, I googled it, but no luck at all.

I tried to use `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcess(pckagename)`, but it also does not remove the task from a recent task list.

I also tried the link
[Android, how to clear the recent task list which could get from Home button in most phone? Reflection is a possible way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890415/android-how-to-clear-the-recent-task-list-which-could-get-from-home-button-in-m)

I always get the following exception

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
>           removeTask() from pid=23297, uid=10051 requires 
>           android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS

Even if I already specified the `android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS` permission in the manifest.

How can we clear the list of recent tasks programmatically, so that the user can see no recent tasks in a recent task list?

Comment: Please use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42228794/1252158) and you will get the simplest way  to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`REMOVE_TASKS` is a `signature`-level permission. It can only be held by apps written by the developers of the device firmware, such as a device manufacturer or ROM mod author.

Comment: so if we have rooted device then can we perform this operation?????even if i am trying to remove my own task from recent by this way i m not being able to do it....thanks for your reply

Comment: is there any alternate to perform this operation. I want that user can not be able to see the list of recent task by any means.

Comment: @praween: "so if we have rooted device then can we perform this operation?" -- no. "is there any alternate to perform this operation" -- hopefully not. "I want that user can not be able to see the list of recent task by any means" -- then build your own ROM mod.

Comment: New design of the recents list in recent Android versions makes it a mess, and having no option to clean up it from code (with some special permission and without OS signature) is regrettable. I mean others developers' tasks, not your own.

Answer (score 6):

Try this out in android manifest inside the launcher activity:

```
 android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just met with the same problem. My duty was to remove a 3th party app from recent list.

Okay, I don`t know how clear the recent list, but I know, how not to put your app there.
start it with: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag .

This worked for me, I hope I can help with it for you. 
details:
min SDK level 14

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you need to add this:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"
```