# Clear recent apps(when long click home button)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

Is there a way that I can clear the recent apps?

to simply clear the list.

I have tried looking for some answer and I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890415/android-how-to-clear-the-recent-task-list-which-could-get-from-home-button-in-m) but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258980/altering-the-result-of-getrecenttasks ?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno no man its not it,i want my application button to do what the clear recent tasks button do when you click it.

Comment: The answer clear the recent apps by flood it with 20 activities.. isn't it the same you want?

Comment: No man,when you long click the home button,you get to a screen with a list of where have you been recently,and there is a button to clear that list.i want my button to do the exact same thing,to clear all the recent tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i understand you cannot clear recent apps because `REMOVE_TASKS` permission can be used only by system/ROM developers.

The only way that would work is to flood the recent tasks with blank activities but you said it isn't your case.

Final: You cannot do what you want! Only system can do it.

Some questions:

- [Clear all recent tasks Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349958/clear-all-recent-task-programmaticcally)
- [Altering the result of getRecentTasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258980/altering-the-result-of-getrecenttasks)
- [How to remove application from recent application list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list)
- [Android, how to clear the recent task list which could get from Home button in most phone? Reflection is a possible way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890415/android-how-to-clear-the-recent-task-list-which-could-get-from-home-button-in-m)