# How to remove application or activity from recent task

Tags: java, android

I am using Broadcast receiver to start my activity..

Broadcast Receiver Called Using Alarm Manager:

```
AlarmManager mAlarmManager = 
    (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent mIntent = 
    new Intent(this, BrodcastRec.class);

PendingIntent mPendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this, 
        0, 
        mIntent, 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, miliSecounds, mPendingIntent);
```

In my Broadcast Receiver

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intentObject = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ActicityWhichIWantToKill.class);
        intentObject.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(intentObject);
}
```

In The ActivityWhichIWantToKill

i will create the function to finishOrKill

```
closeApplication()
{
  finishAffinity();
}
```

> **Solution Which I have Tried**

1.Adding In `Manifest.XML`

```
<Application>
...

<activity android:name=".activity.ActicityWhichIWantToKill"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:noHistory="true"></activity>
....
</Application>
```

2. Adding Flags In Intent Object

   ```
   intentObject.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
   ```
3. Use Intent

   ```
       Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
       homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(homeIntent);
   ```

> My question is how to remove application from recent task ?

I am researching since 3 hours All solution Tried But No Achieved Any Result Can some one Help me to solve this ?

Thanks In Advance......

Comment: You want to remove previous all activities?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha yes but only one activity running which i want to kill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear all recent tasks Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349958/clear-all-recent-tasks-programmatically)

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin sir please read full question i already research about that tried all solution but not work then i will posted this question

Comment: To remove application from REcentTask .Please look at this .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385289/remove-app-from-recent-apps-programmatically

Comment: @altu please read full question i will already tried

Comment: You want to remove your started activity from recent tasks, right?

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin ya which is current running

Comment: You can't do that!! That's why i marked as a duplicate!

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin why i cant do that ? please explain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list see the accepted answer this people do that then why i am not ....

Comment: i dont get you: you have the accepted answer, so why are you asking the same question here? if its not working at your side then ask the author of the accepted answer, why is that...

Comment: @pskink u are 100% right sir......but which author ? there are many question are available with same topic and different answer and this all most of answers i tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468975/2252830